# Pandas Dataframe group them with as long as value is true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

i have created some data:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Time': ['01.10.2019, 09:56:52', '01.10.2019, 10:57:15', '02.10.2019 09:57:23', '02.10.2019 10:02:58', 
              '02.10.2019 10:22:58', '02.10.2019 10:32:55', '02.10.2019, 13:56:52', '02.10.2019, 14:57:15', 
              '02.10.2019 09:57:23', '02.10.2019 10:02:58', '04.10.2019 13:11:58', '04.10.2019 13:22:55']
     ,'Action': ['Closed', 'Opened', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed', 'Opened', 'Closed']
     ,'Name': ['Bayer', 'Bayer', 'ITM', 'ITM', 'ITM' , 'ITM', 'ITM', 'ITM', 'ITM', 'ITM', 'Geco' , 'Geco'],
               'ID': ['2', '2', '2','2','3','3','3','3','1','1','4','4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

And now i want to iterate over every line to see if the next lines name are the same names and create a new column which has boolean as type:

```
df['next_name'] = df['Name'].shift(-1)
df=df.fillna('')
df['sort_key']= df[['next_name','Name']].apply(lambda row: True if row['next_name'] in row['Name'] else False, axis=1)
```

so what im actually trying is to iterate again line by line and to check as long as the sort_key is true it should create a new group with a number. If the sort_key is going to be false it should end to group in group 1 for example and start to create another new group. After that i want to group them again and filter them out.

```
for i in df:
    while i['test'] == True:
       groupmethod?
```

so this is the output if i print after sort_key:

```
    Time                    Action  Name    ID  next_name   sort_key
0   01.10.2019, 09:56:52    Closed  Bayer   2   Bayer       True
1   01.10.2019, 10:57:15    Opened  Bayer   2   ITM         False
2   02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened  ITM     2   ITM         True
3   02.10.2019, 10:02:58    Closed  ITM     2   ITM         True
4   02.10.2019, 10:22:58    Opened  ITM     3   ITM         True
5   02.10.2019, 10:32:55    Closed  ITM     3   ITM         True
6   02.10.2019, 13:56:52    Opened  ITM     3   ITM         True
7   02.10.2019, 14:57:15    Closed  ITM     3   ITM         True
8   02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened  ITM     1   ITM         True
9   02.10.2019, 10:02:58    Closed  ITM     1   Geco        False
10  04.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened  Geco    4   Geco        True
11  04.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed  Geco    4               True
```

and i wished to have my output after group numbers like this:

```
    Time                    Action  Name    ID  next_name   group
0   01.10.2019, 09:56:52    Closed  Bayer   2   Bayer       0
1   01.10.2019, 10:57:15    Opened  Bayer   2   ITM         0
2   02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened  ITM     2   ITM         1
3   02.10.2019, 10:02:58    Closed  ITM     2   ITM         1
4   02.10.2019, 10:22:58    Opened  ITM     3   ITM         1
5   02.10.2019, 10:32:55    Closed  ITM     3   ITM         1
6   02.10.2019, 13:56:52    Opened  ITM     3   ITM         1
7   02.10.2019, 14:57:15    Closed  ITM     3   ITM         1
8   02.10.2019, 09:57:23    Opened  ITM     1   ITM         1
9   02.10.2019, 10:02:58    Closed  ITM     1   Geco        1
10  04.10.2019, 13:11:58    Opened  Geco    4   Geco        2
11  04.10.2019, 13:22:55    Closed  Geco    4               2
```

to get that with my next conditions:

```
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df.sort_values(['Time','ID'],inplace=True)
df['total_diff']=df.groupby(['Name','ID'])['Time'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().dt.total_seconds()).fillna(-1)
df = pd.concat([df[df['Action']=='Opened'].groupby(['Name','ID',df.Time.dt.date,]).min().rename(columns={'Time':'act_time'}).reset_index(),\
df[df['Action']=='Closed'].groupby(['Name','ID',df.Time.dt.date]).max().rename(columns={'Time':'act_time'}).reset_index()]).sort_values('act_time')

df=df[(df['total_diff']>300)|(df['total_diff']==-1)]
df['count']=df.groupby(['Name','Time', 'ID'])['Action'].count().reset_index(drop=True)
df=df[df['count']>1]
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID'])
```

how could i do that? is there a better soloution?

Comment: i have added my expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `shift` and `cumsum`:

```
df["group"] = df["Name"].ne(df["Name"].shift()).cumsum()

print (df)

                    Time  Action   Name ID  group
0   01.10.2019, 09:56:52  Closed  Bayer  2      1
1   01.10.2019, 10:57:15  Opened  Bayer  2      1
2    02.10.2019 09:57:23  Opened    ITM  2      2
3    02.10.2019 10:02:58  Closed    ITM  2      2
4    02.10.2019 10:22:58  Opened    ITM  3      2
5    02.10.2019 10:32:55  Closed    ITM  3      2
6   02.10.2019, 13:56:52  Opened    ITM  3      2
7   02.10.2019, 14:57:15  Closed    ITM  3      2
8    02.10.2019 09:57:23  Opened    ITM  1      2
9    02.10.2019 10:02:58  Closed    ITM  1      2
10   04.10.2019 13:11:58  Opened   Geco  4      3
11   04.10.2019 13:22:55  Closed   Geco  4      3
```